# cannon js - Object has no method 'norm'

Tags: javascript, opengl-es

I am using threejs and cannonjs with collada models

I am receiving this error, however gathering physics per frame(i.e. console counting each physical movement per frame).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'norm'
```

Stack Trace(js debug):

---

```
CANNON.Box.computeBoundingSphereRadius cannon.js:2037
CANNON.Broadphase.doBoundingSphereBroadphase cannon.js:3568
CANNON.Broadphase.intersectionTest cannon.js:3526
CANNON.NaiveBroadphase.collisionPairs cannon.js:3784
CANNON.World.step cannon.js:4816
updatePhysics cannon.demo.js:598
animate
```

Code:

---

shape1 and 2 are complex collada(.dae) models using threejs with cannon.js

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

```
var shape1 = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Shape(shape1));

var shape2 = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Shape(shape2));
```

Version Notes:

---

• cannonjs Version 0.6.0

• threejs REVISION 66

• Collada Loader: https://github.com/rmx/threejs-collada/blob/master/js/ColladaLoader.js

Answer (score 1):

CANNON.Box takes a vector of half-extents as constructor argument. For example:

```
var shape1 = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1));

var shape2 = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1,1,1));
```

Of course, you need to replace "1,1,1" with the right dimensions for your boxes.